# XSL apply template outside of hierarchy using variable from current context

Tags: xslt

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<Zoo>
  <Keepers>
    <Keeper name="Joe" manager="Miles" />
    <Keeper name="Bob" manager="Karen"/>
  </Keepers>
  <Animals>
    <Animal type="tiger" keeper="Joe"/>
    <Animal type="lion" keeper="Joe"/>
    <Animal type="giraffe" keeper="Bob"/>
  </Animals>
</Zoo>
```

I basically want to use Keeper.name as a variable and then apply a template to the matching Animal nodes where Keeper.name = Animal.keeper.

Is this possible using apply-templates or some other kind of XSL syntax?

In my example I want to remove all Keepers managed by Miles and remove all Animal nodes kept by keepers managed by Miles, therefore I would apply blank templates.

Here's my sudo XSL which does not quite work:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@manager='Miles']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Zoo/Animals/Animal[@keeper=current()/@name]"/>
    <!-- apply a blank template to this Keeper -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Animal">
    <!-- apply a blank template to this Animal -->
</xsl:template>
```

My desired output XML is the following:

```
<Zoo>
  <Keepers>
    <Keeper name="Bob" manager="Karen"/>
  </Keepers>
  <Animals>
    <Animal type="giraffe" keeper="Bob"/>
  </Animals>
</Zoo>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where did Snowy in your output come from ? There is no way to connect you input to your output at all

Comment: Kevin - fixed my example sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, given the input listed, this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:param name="removeKeeper">Miles</xsl:param>
        <xsl:template match="Keeper">
            <xsl:if test="not(@manager=$removeKeeper)">
                <Keeper>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                </Keeper>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Animal">
            <xsl:variable name="keeper" select="@keeper"/>
            <xsl:if test="//Keepers/Keeper[@name=$keeper][not(@manager=$removeKeeper)]">
                <Animal>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                </Animal>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields this output:

```
   <Zoo>
      <Keepers>

       <Keeper name="Bob" manager="Karen"/>
      </Keepers>
     <Animals>


          <Animal type="giraffe" keeper="Bob"/>
     </Animals>
    </Zoo>
```

You can also, to be a bit more generic, use:

```
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
```

Instead of the explicit Keeper and Animal tags in the XSL. Up to you.